# Connecting to local MySQL server with RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I'm successfully able to connect to a local MySQL server with the following R script:

```
library(RMySQL)

drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user="root", pass="myrootpass")
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, statement = "SHOW DATABASES;")
fetch(rs)
```

However, I don't want my password to be in the script since it will be saved in a file! I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, MySQL 5.5.35, MySQL Workbench 6.0 and R 3.0.1.

At work, I use Windows, and I'm able to connect to a SQL Server to which I have access without a password with the following lines:

```
library(RODBC)
dbhandle<-odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=SomeServer;database=SomeDatabase;trusted_connection=true')
```

In this case, it seems as if it is sufficient that I have logged in as an employee who has access to the server.

I would like to accomplish something similar to this - how can I connect to a local MySQL Server with my Ubuntu computer?

Comment: It maybe dangerous to use MySQL's "root" user for data processing work. Anyway, MySQL has a fine-grained access control. You could add a user without a password that is only allowed to connect from localhost.

Answer (score 1):

First, create the following .csv and name it "database_credentials.csv"

```
user,password,dbname,host
your_user_name_here,your_password_here,your_database_address_aka_database_name_here,your_hostname_here
```

**If this is a local connection, then in the host field in the .csv file above enter "localhost"**

Then do this

```
# R Script for
# CONNECTING TO DATABASE
  library(RMySQL)
  dbCredentialsFile <- read.csv("database_credentials.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
  con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
  user = dbCredentialsFile$user[1],
  password = dbCredentialsFile$password[1],
  host = dbCredentialsFile$host[1],
  dbname = dbCredentialsFile$dbname[1])
  rm(dbCredentialsFile)
  gc()

# FUNCTION FOR QUERYING DATABASE
  query <- function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...)

# EXAMPLE FOR QUERYING DATABASE
  testDF <- query("SELECT * FROM name_of_table_in_database_to_retrive")
```

Answer (score 0):

set up an option file with your user, password, etc. as discussed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) .